# What is the "about:blank" context for browser security and privacy?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, privacy, same-origin-policy

[This blog is describing a way to hide the referer header](http://webstersprodigy.net/2013/02/01/stripping-the-referer-in-a-cross-domain-post-request/) in various situations.  Specifically he is referring to things that run in the `about:blank` context.

- What is the `about:blank` context?
- How does `about:blank`, 307 redirect, and CORS relate to this? (or how would I determine this outside of the blog?)
- Are there additional things that run in the about:blank context besides those listed?
- Are there other security contexts that run in parallel to `about:blank`?

Comment: First of all i don't think its possible to run JS in about:blank (or the local security context) unless you have an 0-day...  That being said, about:blank probably isn't useful to anyone.

Comment: @rook I'm soon going to experiment with an iFrame with `src=about:blank`.  Test cases and other ideas are welcome

Comment: Beware when you use about:blank in an https website. The about:blank is in a different zone and some browsers will throw an annoying warning about 'mixed content'

Comment: In the case of data URI's, **IIRC** each URI seems isolated from every other. I.e. `data:text/html;,foo` cannot contact `data:text/html;,bar`. This may then also apply to `about:`'s

Answer (score 1):

The `about:blank` is just a blank address-less browser screen, that will inherit the same security parameters of its caller. That said, you cannot exploit `about:blank` to bridge the JavaScript cross-domain access restrictions if thats what you're asking.

Despite its `location` is not part of your domain, it belongs to it, and will not run stuff in a different security level.